# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'PCA' and 'float'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

EDIT:

Here is the head of the data csv:

```
    Fresh   Milk    Grocery Frozen  Detergents_Paper    Delicatessen
0   12669   9656    7561    214 2674    1338
1   7057    9810    9568    1762    3293    1776
2   6353    8808    7684    2405    3516    7844
3   13265   1196    4221    6404    507 1788
4   22615   5410    7198    3915    1777    5185
```

Error I'm seeing:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'PCA' and 'float'
```

Code:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

log_data = np.log(data)

# TODO: Apply PCA to the good data with the same number of dimensions as features
pca = PCA(n_components=4)

# TODO: Apply a PCA transformation to the sample log-data
pca_samples = pca.fit(log_data)

# Generate PCA results plot
pca_results = rs.pca_results(good_data, pca)

display(pd.DataFrame(np.round(pca_samples, 4), columns = pca_results.index.values))
```

It's complaining about the last line

data is from a csv that has been shown to work fine.

Comment: add a representative portion of the CSV file at the top of your script as a `StringIO` object and load it as a part of your example.

Comment: Please include the stack trace so we know where the problem is.

Comment: What is `rs`? And the `np.log` line raising the error isn't shown. Is there more to this script?

Comment: @PaulH I added it at the top of the question

Comment: @tdelaney rs refers to: import renders as rs

Comment: `pca_samples` is a `PCA` object (see [PCA.fit()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.fit)) so `np.round(pca_samples, 4)` fails. That is likely the problem... though a stack trace showiing a fail in `np.round` would be helpful.

Comment: You are right @tdelaney.  I found the issue.  I did not run the transformation on the pca_samples line.  Just the fit.  You can leave an answer and I'll give you the checkmark if you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PCA.fit()` tansforms the model in-place and returns `self` so that you can chain other model operations. So, after

```
pca_samples = pca.fit(log_data)
```

`pca_samples` is just another reference to `pca`.

Answer (score 3):

`pca.fit(X[, y])` just fit the model with X, and return the `self`, that is pca itself.

Since that you want to get the transformed data with

```
pd.DataFrame(np.round(pca_samples, 4), columns = pca_results.index.values))
```

So, you should call `pca.fit_transform()`

> fit_transform(X[, y])  Fit the model with X and apply the dimensionality reduction on X.

See the [docs of pca](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA), and [fit_transform](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.fit_transform)

Answer (score 0):

For your code to work please see below tested code and the line you should change!

```
#TODO: Transform log_samples using the PCA fit above

pca_samples = pca.fit_transform(log_samples)
```

The above code works very well.